# Questions on regarding convexity of the Minkowski functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm currently revising functional analysis and having some trouble with basic definitions. Two of the problems are given below:

$1)$ Let $C$ be an open convex set and $x\in C$. Why is it true that $(1+\epsilon)x\in C$, for $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary small? I've seen on this site an argument with open balls but I don't understand it, and using the definition of convexity doesn't produce anything fruitful (or perhaps I wasn't doing it right.  Can one use the definition of convexity here to prove this?).

$2)$ Let $p$ denote the Minkowski functional, that is 
$$p(x)= \inf\left\{t>0: \frac{x}{t}\in C\right\}.$$
I'm having trouble understanding the proof of the sub-additivity property. Given below:

[image]

Where does the inequality $\lambda > p(x)$ stem from and how does it follow that $\displaystyle\frac{x}{\lambda}$?

Comment: In 1, I believe you need $C$ to be open for this to be true. Convexity is not necessary. The fact that $\lambda > p(x) \implies x/\lambda \in C$ should follow from the definition of $p(x)$. (Though I do feel like we need something more from $C$, perhaps that it is also circled...)

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist you are correct and I've made the necessary changes. But my question is why is the ϵ -neighborhood of a convex set is convex?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by an $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of a convex set. However, even given an appropriate definition, whether these neighbourhoods are convex or not is not relevant to whether $(1+\varepsilon ) x \in C$ for all small enough $\varepsilon$.